# Cómo refresco un fragment que tiene un RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, navigation-drawer

Compañeros, estoy intentando hacer una app que refresque los datos que estoy mostrando en un RecyclerView (Un carrito de compras), le agregue un boton de eliminar, los datos en pantalla se borran normalmente pero no me actualiza el total, y dicho total se actualiza solo si cambio de fragmento. favor me pueden ayudar?
Nota: Estoy trabajando con Navigation Drawer

*** Este es mi adaptador

```
    public class AdaptadorCarrito extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCarrito.ViewHolderCarrito>
    {

        ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> TotalcarroCompra;
        TextView tvTotal;
        double total = 0;
        Context context;
        ImageView eliminar_servicio;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

        public AdaptadorCarrito(ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> carroCompra, TextView tvTotal, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
            this.TotalcarroCompra = carroCompra;
            this.tvTotal = tvTotal;
            this.sharedPreferences=sharedPreferences;

            for(int i = 0 ; i < carroCompra.size() ; i++) {
                total = total + Double.parseDouble(""+carroCompra.get(i).getPrecio_servicio());
            }
            BigDecimal total_carrito = new BigDecimal(total);
            total_carrito= total_carrito.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            tvTotal.setText(""+"$"+total_carrito.doubleValue()+"0");
        }

  @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderCarrito onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_carro_compras,null,false);
        return (new ViewHolderCarrito(view));
    }
```

**Este es mi método que elimina cada item, si los elimina

```
  public void removePosition(int position) {
         if (position!=-1)
             TotalcarroCompra.remove(position);
             Gson gson = new Gson();
             String json = gson.toJson(TotalcarroCompra);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
             editor.putString("server_peluqueria", json);
             editor.apply();
             notifyItemRemoved(position);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

en un botonConfirmation llamó a ese método, a lo que borro el item quiero que el fragment se me actualice, por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar, se los agredecería mucho

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderCarrito holder, final int position) {

    eliminar_servicio = (ImageView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_server);
    eliminar_servicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final  ViewHolderCarrito holderCarrito = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
            //int position = holderCarrito.getAdapterPosition();
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(position));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Está seguro que desea eliminar el servicio ?");
            builder.setTitle("Te Informa: ");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.iconrasel);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    removePosition(position);
                  Toasty.success(view.getContext(),"El Servicio ha sido eliminado...", Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    holder.nombre_servicio.setText(TotalcarroCompra.get(position).getNombre_servicio());
    holder.precio_servicio.setText("$"+TotalcarroCompra.get(position).getPrecio_servicio()+"0");
    holder.imagen_servicio.setImageResource(TotalcarroCompra.get(position).getImagen_servicio());
}

  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (TotalcarroCompra != null)
            return TotalcarroCompra.size();
        return 0;

    }
```

***Este es mi fragmento donde llamo a  ese adptador

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carrito, container, false);

       preferencesPeluqueria =
                getActivity().getSharedPreferences("carroPeluqueria", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json = preferencesPeluqueria.getString("server_peluqueria","");

        if(carroCompras.size()>0 && !carroCompras.isEmpty()){
           PeluqueriaDAO p = carroCompras.get(0);
           rvListaCarro = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvListaCarro);
           rvListaCarro.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
           rvListaCarro.setHasFixedSize(true);
           tvTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
           adaptador = new AdaptadorCarrito(carroCompras,tvTotal,preferencesPeluqueria);
           rvListaCarro.setAdapter(adaptador);
           adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }else {
            Toasty.warning(view.getContext(),"El Carrito esta vacío", Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Si llamas a `removePosition` que entiendo que está en la clase del adapter, desde la clase del fragment, una vez lo llamas, podrías actualizar lo que quieras del fragment, extrayendo lo que haces al cargar el fragment a otra función y llamándola cuando cargas el fragment y cuando has llamado a `removePosition`.

Comment: Estimado gracias por responder, me podría orientar como  hacer eso, como llamar ese método remove al fragment

Comment: Saca a una función en el fragment lo que haces para actualizar el total. Cuando se inicia el fragment, haces la llamada a la función, con lo que nada habrá cambiado. Luego en el momento en el que en el fragment vas a llamar a `removePosition`, pasándole la posición, justo después, vuelves a llamar a la función que hiciste para que te actualice el total. El tema es meter en una función la actualización del total para llamarla al iniciar el fragment y cuando cambies tú algo. Para ponerte un ejemplo, publica tu fragment, al menos las funciones que entra en este tema, y el adapter.

Comment: Estimado, ya modifique mi pregunta y le agregue mas codigo, para ser le sincero no le comprendo bien , de todas maneras muchas gracias por la ayuda,  le agregue el codigo del fragment y el adapter

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar darte una solución teniendo en cuenta el código que nos presentas.

El adapter recibe por constructor el TextView tvTotal que muestra el total del carrito, y se setea en el momento de crear la instancia.

Al hacer el remove del item, estás actualizando la lista pero no el TextView que se pasó por constructor, así que lo que debes hacer es, al borrar un artículo, volver a calcular el precio de los artículos actuales y volver a setear ese TextView.

Así que crea un método externo que calcule el precio total y otro que haga el populate, de esta manera reutilizas el código.